# How to set width of HTML / CSS button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to set the width of the button. I have added "width" but it makes no difference.

```
<tr>
    <td data- 
 bgcolor="bg-button" data-size="size button" data-min="10" data- 
 max="20" 
 class="btn" align="center" style="font:bold 16px/18px Arial, 
Helvetica, 
sans-serif; color:#f9f9f9; text-transform:uppercase; mso-padding- 
alt:12px 20px; border-radius:0px; width:200px"   bgcolor="#e1e000">
<a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#231f20; 
display:block; padding:10px 5px;" href="#">Play now</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can't easily set the width of a `td` and I'm not sure why you are in the first place. Just use a `div`instead....or, you know, an actual `button`.

Comment: adjust the padding, ex: padding 10px 15px;

Comment: Is this a button for an email or webpage?

Comment: This is a button for an email

Comment: Are you able to adjust the width property from 200px to another value? How much of this email template are you able to change?

As you've given us only a small sample, the width may be restrained by the content of previous table rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm now trying to figure out how to put the image over bg image on a td

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a container table within your TD to set the button size, you can see in the code below that i've wrapped it in a table. This allows you to set the exact width of the button, you can also center the button within the row by adding align="center" to the container table.

```
    <tr>
  <td align="center">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
      <tr>
    <td data- 
 bgcolor="bg-button" data-size="size button" data-min="10" data- 
 max="20" 
 class="btn" align="center" style="font:bold 16px/18px Arial, 
Helvetica, 
sans-serif; color:#f9f9f9; text-transform:uppercase; mso-padding- 
alt:12px 20px; border-radius:0px;"   bgcolor="#e1e000">
<a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#231f20; 
display:block; padding:10px 5px;" href="#">Play now</a>
   </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I also recommend looking at https://buttons.cm/ if you wish to create buttons that work across all email clients/browsers.

Comment: I'd like to also set the background image of the TD and add the button in a certain place, is that possible?